# How to not get special characters in place of meta key combinations for VIM on OS X

Tags: macos, vim, osx-lion, macvim, osx-mountain-lion

On OS X, at any program, when I type <kbd>option-p</kbd> I get `π`, <kbd>option-P</kbd> I get `∏` and there's a bunch of <kbd>alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> bindings that just return greek and other special characters.

Is there a way to disable that?

Currently I'm using the [Auto Pairs VIM plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599) and it has the following default mappings:

```
<M-p> : Toggle Autopairs (g:AutoPairsShortcutToggle) 
<M-e> : Fast Wrap (g:AutoPairsShortcutFastWrap) 
<M-n> : Jump to next closed pair (g:AutoPairsShortcutJump) 
<M-b> : BackInsert (g:AutoPairsShortcutBackInsert)
```

It seems I can't use these and other meta key based VIM mappings while this special input is turned on.

**EDIT**

From [this cnet article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20097505-263/options-for-character-input-in-os-x-lion/), in truth I need to know how to disable that special input shown at the bottom of the page.

Comment: did you figure this out? having the same issue

Answer (score 14):

Use the `macmeta` setting: `:set macmeta`

From `:help 'macmeta'`

> 'macmeta' Use option (alt) as meta key.  When on, option-key presses are not interpreted, thus enabling bindings to `<M-..`>.  When off, option-key presses are interpreted by the selected input method and inserted as text.

Obviously this is a MacVim-only setting.

In Terminal.app Settings there's a setting for "Use option as meta key", under the *Keyboard* tab which disables e.g. <kbd>Option-p</kbd> printing *π*. You may need to start a new terminal window to see the effect. But for some reason even after disabling this I'm having trouble setting mappings for `<M-p>`, but mappings using <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> and inserting the character literally **do** work.

Comment: The only caveat is that it is {only available in MacVim GUI} =(. I would like to know how to turn it off system wide.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it seems that with MacVim, in my .vimrc I can just map these special characters and it will work both at GUI and at Terminal.

Since they are generated by the corresponding meta key combinations, it'll look just as a meta key mapping.

**EDIT**

Some special characters are accents and it may not work well for them.

I've done this at my `.vimrc`:

```
if has("gui_macvim")
  let g:AutoPairsShortcutToggle     = 'π' " <m-p>
  let g:AutoPairsShortcutFastWrap   = '∑' " <m-w>
  let g:AutoPairsShortcutJump       = '∆' " <m-j>
  let g:AutoPairsShortcutBackInsert = '∫' " <m-b>
endif
```

`has("gui_macvim")` is true both at GUI as at Terminal, when running MacVim.