# how to remap <C-;>

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I want to use the following code to quickly go from insert mode -> command mode. The problem is it just doesnt seem to be registering my keys. I've tried with control (nothing happens) and i've also tried with command (D) and it just says spellcheck not activated.

```
" Quick command mode from insert
imap <C-;> <esc>:
```

How do i go about doing this? is there an easier vim way that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> chords can't be mapped, including <kbd>Ctrl-;</kbd>.

This is mentioned in [this FAQ](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-20.5), see also the [Vim FAQ](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html):

> 20.4. I am not able to create a mapping for the `<xxx>` key. What is wrong?
>
> First make sure that the key is passed to Vim. In insert mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>
>   followed by the desired key.  You should see the keycode corresponding to
>   the key.  If you do see the keycode, then you can create a mapping for the
>   key using the following command:
>
> ```
> :map <C-V><xxx> <your_command_to_be_mapped>
> ```
>
> For more information, read
>
> ```
> :help map-keys-fails
> :help :map-special-keys
> :help key-codes
> ```

The tip about trying to print the character using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> is good to remember if you run into this problem with another key combo.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it, however it doesn't seem to work, also as pb2q said, it just can't be mapped. But there are other ways to escape using a Ctrl key combination.

For example, you can also escape insert mode with the following key presses:

1. `Ctrl-[`
2. `Ctrl-c`

Answer (score 1):

On OS X (I think Lion and above), you are able to map <kbd>alt - ;</kbd> using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904947/1000282), <kbd>alt - ;</kbd> on OS X outputs ç, which you can map.

But at a MacBook, I prefer to use [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) to map <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd>. Or at Windows, use a [tool I've created myself for that](http://oblita.com/Interception.html) or even [Ctrl2Cap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578.aspx).

**EDIT**

oh sorry, I thought you wanted to switch to normal mode, that's why I talked about <kbd>caps lock</kbd> mappings.